# Is disk version of iWork 08 compatible with El Capitan

Tags: ios, macos, iwork

Opened a iWork 08 Pages file created in 2015 and very little appears.  All text is white and can’t be changed to black. This was not a problem on my previous OS.  IS this a El Capitan issue?

Comment: Read the disk box for the application, and see if it has a Mac version of OS X that it is compatible with

Comment: Did you try changing the typeface in addition to the color of the type? Can you save the file in RTF format and open it in TextEdi?

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed iWork from disc you **may** be able to then upgrade to the latest version via the App Store. It's been a while since I tried it but it worked a few years ago.

That would then give you a compatible version that can open the older files.